# Rectangle randomly thrown on chessboard

Tags: probability, geometry, random

)

I'm an electrical engineer and having a tough problem with... math :) geometry and probability...

Here's the problem :

- We have an infinite chessboard. Each square of the chessboard is of known height/width (x).
- I have four points, distances between these points being FIXED. They can be arranged as a rectangle, square, diamond, on a circle...

Question : I want to throw the rectangle (or square, or diamond...) on the chessboard and get a 100% probability for two points of the rectangle to land on a white square and the two other points on a black square.

- What shape/dimensions regarding to x, do I have to adopt for this condition to be fullfilled ?

Thanks for your help :) !

Comment: There is no need to have a variable $x$. Simply take $x=1$, since any solution can be scaled by a factor $x$ afterwards otherwise.

Comment: This really isn't a probability question, since you want to guarantee the result you're after, rather than trying to maximize its probability or something.

Comment: I don't think you can guarantee this in general, though.   I suspect that a square of any size (relative to the checkerboard square side length) can be placed so that all four corners lie on squares of the same color.

Comment: I'm also of the opinion that this is impossible. Would be happy to be proven wrong, though =)

Comment: If a vertex is on the edge between a black and white square, is it on both or on neither?

Comment: The probability of that is neglegible, @Regret. It is a null set.

Comment: String, that's right !
BrianTung, that's right too for the probability :)
@Regret A vertex cannot be on both squares since a vertex is infinitly small :)

Comment: I was thinking of n-uncounts regarding to the square size... maybe this could help solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any set of four vertices, $\{A,B,C,D\}$. We will only be focusing on three of them, however, as only three need to land on the same color in order to contradict your wishes.

$AB$ defines a line. Draw a line perpendicular to $AB$ that passes through $C$. You now have a cross that passes through $A$, $B$ and $C$. Now the cross can be placed on the grid like so:

$\hskip 250 px$[image: Chess]

$A, B, C$ will all be on black squares. If only one or zero of the vertices is on the corner of a square, the cross can be *translated or rotated within a probabilistically non-negligible area*. This is also the case after the following transformations:

If all three vertices are on corners, the cross can be rotated slightly about its center so all are now on white. If only $A,B$ are on corners, the cross can be translated along $AB$ to get them off the corners. If only $C$ and one of $A,B$ are on corners, then the cross can be translated slightly horizontally or vertically and rotated slightly about its center.

Therefore, for every quadrilateral there is a nonzero probability that three of its vertices will land on the same color.

Comment: Let me know if I have made a mistake or if you need clarification on something. I understand that this answer is not very rigorous, but I believe the reasoning is sound and it could be made rigorous.

Comment: I see no mistake or anything that is not clear. There is no need to mention four points, however. It suffices to show, as you did, that any triangle can have its vertices placed on the same color in a way that is non-negligible. This contradicts the possibility of the desired construction.

Comment: @String: I began with four vertices just to address the question more explicitly, but I think I will edit the answer to mention your point.

Comment: Apart from that, I really like your description! It is simple and clear. And even rigorous - there is no need to let simplicity or geometrical arguments suggest otherwise. Formalism is nothing, but a language to break down things, that cannot be broken down by simpler and more intuitive arguments.

Comment: @String: Thank you! I appreciate your feedback and encouraging words. Do you think the current edit is alright?

Comment: Yes, I think it is very fine like this!

Comment: Thank you very much for the input !
Well, I did expect that result. But nevertheless, I've got a real world problem to solve :) By any chance, do you know any pattern where a configuration of 4 vertexes that guarantees the "two on white, two on black" condition actually exists ? You may have infered it but my goal is to have cathodes and anodes on a plane and throw 4 contacts plugs on it (with diode bridges) to charge a battery just by throwing it randomly on the plane surface.

Comment: And if that condition cannot be guaranteed, maybe some pattern/vertex placement that could *minify* the probability of having the '4 black' or '4 white' configuration (which would make battery charging impossible).

Comment: @ChessLooser: I can't think of anything off the top of my head. It may be a good idea to ask and explain all that in a new question.

Comment: @Regret Allright, thanks very much ;)